# simultaneous word problem

Tags: systems-of-equations

A farmer uses 50 m  of fencing to enclose a rectangular area against a long straight wall. What must be the dimensions of the enclosure if its area is to be $300 m^2$?
The question requires the use of simultaneous equation to solve.

Here is what is obtained, but not sure why solving the equation got complex answers. Did I form the equation incorrectly? The equation seems alright to me. Answers: length = 30, width = 10 or length 20, width = 15

length = x,
width = y

$$area: xy = 300$$
$$perimeter: 2x+2y=50 => x+y =25$$

$$y=25-x$$
$$x(25-x)=300$$
$$25x-x^2=300$$
$$x^2-25x+300 = 0$$ (got complex when solving for x, which is incorrect)

Comment: Notice that one of the edges of the area is not built with the fencing, but rather is a wall. So instead of
$$
2x+2y = 50 
$$
you should have put
$$
x + 2y = 50
$$

Comment: Thanks got it. Misinterpreted it.